# How do I call C++ code when a button is clicked in a WPF application in C#?

Tags: c++, wpf, wrapper

I don't have any idea of how a connection between wpf and c++ code is made. I have added a `record` button in my wpf application. Is it possible to wrap the c++ solution here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855374.aspx so that when the `record` button is pushed in the wpf, the c++ solution will get executed?

Comment: WPF applications can be written in C++. My guess is yours is written in C#. Can you make that clear in the question?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. You can use P/Invoke or a C++/CLI wrapper.

Or you could actually read that page your provided and find a link that says [For more information about audio, see Capturing Audio Data in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855349.aspx).

Comment: well the thing is that for some reason the c# code exports single track wav files, while I want to use all 4 tracks. The c++ code exports all 4 tracks of Kinect microphone array.